# How to find in sales/order/print/ page Magento 2?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento version 2.1.3.

How can I customize order page? The path is showing the URL:

```
sales/order/print/ page
```

Where can I find the page?

[image: Description]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this about Magento, not programming, and belongs on https://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
$currentUrl = $this->getUrl('', ['_current' => true]);
$urlRewrite = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', [
    '_current' => true, 
    '_use_rewrite' => true
]);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Your answer Core php ,.. Not Mangento